# Need to detect beginning and ending xml tags

Tags: xml, regex

Techies--

I am capturing data from a 3rd party api. I'm simplifying the xml from this to send to mssql through a stored procedure. I can't always rely on the first property.Name.LocalName in the where clause will truly be the first element coming back. This would be true for the last element as well. Unfortunately, I coded for the wrong assumption.

Here's the abbreviated logic:

```
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(nodeReader, settings);
            XElement data = XElement.Load(reader);
            XmlNameTable table = reader.NameTable;
            XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(table);
            manager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
            manager.AddNamespace("m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
            manager.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");
            manager.AddNamespace("base", "https://api20.ourthirdparty.com:4400/odata/v2/");
            foreach (XElement entries in data.XPathSelectElements("./ns:entry", manager))
            {
                foreach (var contents in (from entry in entries.Elements() where entry.Name.LocalName.Contains("content") select entry))
                {
                    foreach (var properties in (from content in contents.Elements() where content.Name.LocalName.Contains("properties") select content))
                    {

                        foreach (var property in (from property in properties.Elements()
                                                  where property.Name.LocalName.Contains("startDate")
                                                        || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("userId")
                                                        || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("seqNumber")
                                                        || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("fte")

                                select property)

                                 )
```

Here is where the Xml is simplified for mssql server consumption

```
                            // get all the instances the positions w/tags and values
                            sb.Append(string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", property.Name.LocalName, property.Value, property.Name.LocalName));

                        // add the root tag sets
                        docEmpJobs = begtag + sb.ToString() + endtag;

                    }

                }

            }
```

Here is where my assumption is incorrect about start/end tag placement--

```
            // Correct missing tags with regex

            Regex tag1 = new Regex(@"<startDate>");
            Regex tag2 = new Regex(@"</fte>");
            docEmpJobs = tag1.Replace(docEmpJobs, "<EmpJob><startDate>");
            docEmpJobs = tag2.Replace(docEmpJobs, "</fte></EmpJob>");
            // Correct ampersand xml conversion failures


            // Note: The ampersand was an ill-placed value from a test case, but still made it to the raw xml.

            docEmpJobs = docEmpJobs.Replace("&", "and");  // return scrubbed string for xdoc conversion
```

Does anyone have any advice on how I can detect the first tag set and the last tag set for the EmpJob node?

Comment: For the millionth time here: Don't try to parse HTML/XML with regexes. Use a real DOM parser.

Comment: And maybe leverage XPath to find/select elements from XML documents.

Comment: @KenWhite -- you can see the temptation to use regex for these 2 tag sets, right? What is the practical suggestion? GetElementsByTagName, loop through items find 0 then the last under just the dubbed root tags, write out the collection yet again--or something else?

Comment: XPath or Linq to XML would both work to locate the elements. I see zero temptation to try to kludge parsing XML into a regex, and many many reasons not to do so (which is why it's been said here a million times before).